# Get Data from Local Storage JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, local-storage

I work on the Kanban board app, it contains three columns for not started, In progress, and Completed tasks, I can add a new task, edit it, delete it, and drag and drop it from column to column. I save all data to local storage, and now I want to retrieve it back when loading the page and add the functionality of the app as it is.

** if any advice to enhance styling when dragging the task to another column as well?

And please if there is any advice to make the code better.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

I try to set the localStorage.getItem() method but it doesn't work as I expected

Here's my code`

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Kanban Board</title>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Kanban Board</h1>
  <div class="container" id="container">
  </div>

  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    background-color: #009578;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    gap: 6rem;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    user-select: none;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 5rem;
    width: 80%;
}

.column,
.tasks {
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
    width: 30rem;
}

.input-container {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}

.field {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.edit {
    color: #002d24;
}

.remove {
    color: red;
}

.btn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    background-color: #00866d;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #006854;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const board = document.getElementById("container");
const columns = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Not Started",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "In Progress",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Completed",
    },
];
let drag = null;

// Create Columns and render in page
columns.forEach((column) => {
    // Create main column
    const columnDiv = document.createElement("div");
    columnDiv.className = "column";
    columnDiv.id = column.id;

    // Create column title
    const columnTitle = document.createElement("h3");
    columnTitle.textContent = column.title;
    columnDiv.appendChild(columnTitle);

    // Create tasks lists
    const tasksList = document.createElement("ul");
    tasksList.className = "tasks";
    columnDiv.appendChild(tasksList);

    // create add buttons
    const addTaskBtn = document.createElement("button");
    addTaskBtn.className = "btn";
    addTaskBtn.textContent = "+ Add";
    columnDiv.appendChild(addTaskBtn);

    // evevt listener for buttons to Add A new task
    addTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const inputContainer = document.createElement("li");
        inputContainer.className = "input-container";
        inputContainer.draggable = true;
        inputContainer.innerHTML = `
            <input type='text' class='field' id='${column.title}-task' placeholder='Task'/>
            <ion-icon name="pencil-outline" class='icon edit'></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon name="trash-outline" class="icon remove"></ion-icon>
            `;
        tasksList.appendChild(inputContainer);
        taskHandlers();
    });

    board.appendChild(columnDiv);
});

// Update localStorage with html structure
const updateLocalStorage = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(
        "pageStructure",
        document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML,
    );
};

// Handle added tasks and control events on it
function taskHandlers() {
    const tasks = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")];
    tasks.forEach((task) => {
        const input = task.querySelector("input");
        const editBtn = task.querySelector(".edit");
        const deleteBtn = task.querySelector(".remove");

        // Save the task
        const saveTask = () => {
            input.setAttribute("disabled", "");
            input.setAttribute("value", input.value);
            input.style.cursor = "move";
            task.setAttribute("dragable", "true");

            updateLocalStorage();
        };

        // Edit task
        const editTask = () => {
            input.disabled = false;
            input.focus();
            input.style.cursor = "auto";
            task.removeAttribute("draggable");

            updateLocalStorage();
        };

        // Delete task
        const deleteTask = () => {
            task.remove();

            updateLocalStorage();
        };

        // Event listneres
        input.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
            saveTask();
        });

        input.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
            if (e.key === "enter") {
                saveTask();
            }
        });

        editBtn.addEventListener("click", editTask);

        deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteTask);

        /*
        *****************
        // Drag and Drop
        *****************
        */
        const dragStart = () => {
            drag = task;
            task.style.opacity = "0.5";
        };

        const dragEnd = () => {
            drag = null;
            task.style.opacity = "1";

            updateLocalStorage();
        };

        task.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
        task.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);

        const lists = document.querySelectorAll("ul");
        lists.forEach((list) => {
            list.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            list.addEventListener("drop", () => {
                list.appendChild(drag);
            });
        });
    });
}

taskHandlers();
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should pass the key that you want in `localStorage.getItem()`. So for instance `localStorage.getItem("tasks")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
localStorage.getItem("pageStructure");
```

Here is more about [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

Comment: Where can i use it  i want to retrieve the structure and still every function also work

Comment: If you refresh or goes to another page you can use localstorage. And if you hope to use in same page better to use global variable or somthing like that

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get from localStorage and insert inside page use this code:

```
let a = localStorage.getItem("pageStructure")
document.getElementById("container").insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', a );
```